# Accessing Python interpreter in Windows Subsytem for Linux, error in sshd_config?

Tags: ssh, python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pycharm

I'm running into an issue with following a tutorial on [How to configure a remote interpreter through WSL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html) for PyCharm. My specific issue comes during the prerequisite part of this tutorial. I get up through step 5, but step 6 says:

> Now that you've installed Linux on your Windows system, you have to edit the ssh configuration file /etc/ssh/sshd_config: change the fields PasswordAuthentication to yes, and UsePrivilegeSeparation to no.

However, my sshd_config file doesn't contain "UsePrivilegeSeparation" and I also don't see a couple of the (possibly unrelated) lines they show in the example image, such as "KeyRegenerationInterval" or "ServerKeyBits".

Whether I ignore this step or try to just manually insert the line, I get errors at step 8. When I run, "sudo $(sudo which sshd) -d", I get:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 60: Deprecated option UsePrivilegeSeparation
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: key_load_private: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: key_load_private: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: key_load_private: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Missing privilege separation directory: /run/sshd
```

So clearly "UsePrivilegeSeparation" is no longer a valid option, but I'm still missing a privilege separation directory.

If I manually create one, it starts to work, but fails when I actually try to connect from a different window:

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: key_load_private: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: key_load_private: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: key_load_private: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8 
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 58061 on 127.0.0.1 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 109/65534 [preauth]
debug1: ssh_sandbox_child: prctl(PR_SET_SECCOMP): Invalid argument [preauth]  
debug1: list_hostkey_types:  [preauth]
No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 136
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

So it is some sort of issue with key exchange, but based on the tutorial that shouldn't be something I have to worry about at all, so I know I must be making some sort of error. What can I do to fix this connection issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue wound up being resolved. I contacted JetBrains, who told me that the tutorial was out of date and UsePrivilegeSeparation was deprecated. However after one of the latest early access builds of PyCharm ([PyCharm 2018.3 EAP 7](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/10/pycharm-2018-3-eap-7/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Pycharm+%28JetBrains+PyCharm+Blog%29)), they have added native support for connecting to interpreters on the Linux subsystem.